# Showing custom element and content with jQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, validation

I've been trying to adapt the Validator Plug in to my needs (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

The plug in displays a message when something is invalid.  Howeever, the content of this message is inside the js file itself (I can change it via the "message:" property). As I'm building a site in several languages, to do this I'd have to have several .js files in which I'd only change the text. I dpn't want to do that, as it is a candidate for a maintainability mess.

What I want is, each rule to take a class or id as an argument, and the error to be shown in that particular element, which would be hidden via CSS (note I simplified the code just for example purposes)

```
<label>Bla:</label>
<input type="text" id="username"/>
<span class="hiddenError" id="requireUser" style="display:none">Write yo name</span>
<span class="hiddenError" id="lengthUser" style="display:none">Write at least 5 characters long</span>
```

So, instead of hardcoding the messages in the js (or the HTML, I don't want to put the initialization on the HTML, please...) I want those .hiddenError to show depending on the error. I'm not sure, but I think it has something to do with

```
errorElement: "label",  
errorContainer: $( [] ),  
errorLabelContainer: $( [] ),
```

but I couldn't get them to work.

Is there a way to do that? I tried modifying the plug in itself, but dealing with more than a thousand lines of code was as difficult as writing a plug in with all those characteristics myself.

Thank you very much in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

That would be a poor way to do i18n in my opinion, by polluting your HTML with many hidden elements.

You are better off constructing an object literal which maps the messages name to the language code.